# How do I send data from a method in DATA class to a jTextArea in guiTest class

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

How do I send data from the method in `Data` class to a `JTextArea` in `GUITest` class, or `System.out.println` redirected to the `JTextArea`?

I need to do it in a way that only when data in `DataOut` method is updated, its sent, not polled for new data from the main method.

This is the sample code

```java
    public class GUITest 

    private JFrame frame;
    JTextArea textArea_1 = new JTextArea();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        
        System.out.println ("Thread Name 0 "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUITest window = new GUITest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        
        Data data = new Data();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(20);
            data.DataOut();
        }
    }

    public GUITest() throws IOException {
    
        initialize();
    }
        
    public  void initialize() throws IOException {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(1200, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        textArea_1.setBounds(120, 45, 100, 23);
        textArea_1.setText("");
        frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_1);
    }
}
```

```java
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Data {

    public void DataOut() throws IOException {
        int S = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            S++;
        }
        System.out.println(S);  // This should print to the JTextArea of class GUITest
    }
}
```

Comment: The logic and design of what you are doing is questionnable. DataOut will not have access the components inside the mainframe. Ideally a controller is used for such purposes. However if you are just looking for a method then it's JTextArea.setText().

Comment: Tried to make an object of main class and I get this error   Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Comment: Do you mean you want to listen to changes in `Data`  ?

Comment: For better readability please stick to [Java Naming conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that. The first thing that comes in my mind is:

Let the Data class constructor accept an istance of GUITest, so it becomes:

```
Data data = new Data(this);
```

and Data becomes:

```
public class Data{
  GUITest istance;

  public Data(GUITest istance){
     this.istance=istance;
  }
}
```

Then, create a method in GUITest called `setTextAreaMessage(String message)` and in the Data class, instead of `System.out.println(S);` you call `istance.setTextAreaMessage(S);`
Don't forget to set the text inside the `setTextAreaMessage(String message)` method with the line `text_Area1.setText(message);`

This solution works, but honestly I don't remember if you can declare a widget like jTextArea as static. If you can, you can just do something like `GUITest.text_Area1.setText(S);`

Comment: Data data = new Data(this);  in main class gives an error of Cannot use this in static context, but also shouldn't a solution to this involve using the invokelater swing thread?

Comment: The problem is that your code design is as hard to read as the logic of what you want to do. First of all, comment out all the lines that involve the thread and simply try to setText from your Data class to your GUITest as I did.

Comment: GUITest.text_Area1.setText(S); this worked but, shouldn't I be updating the gui in Swing thread using EventQueue.invokeLater, isn't that the proper way to do it ?

Comment: Ok got it working, just had to put GUITest.text_Area1.setText(S); inside a new thread.